# Simple sliding window protocol example results analyses

Tags: networking

This the link to the question and answer.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-2006-question-44/

I am confused at two places:

1. Why they convert the 32 byte in bits?
2. How they calculate value of n?

```
utilization = n/(1+2a)
a = Tp / Tt
here : Tp = 80ms, Tt 2ms
a = 80/2 = 40

utilization = n/(1+2*40)
```

According to this answer should be 81, but correct answer is 41. How on that site, how?

Comment: Tp should be 40ms. Round Trip propagation delay ~ 2 * Tp.

Comment: roundtrip time is the time from sender to receiver then back to sender.